# Android tv зафиксировать фокус

Tags: android, focus

Есть ViewPager c двумя вкладками (вкладка = фрагмент), в каждой вкладке RecyclerView со своим адаптером в который подгружаются элементы

```
((AdapterVideo) rv.getAdapter()).addItems(items);
rv.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
rv.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

После каждой подгрузки начисто слетает фокус. Особенно плохо когда фокус слетает на вкладку которая закрыта.

**Как можно заблокировать фокус на каком либо элементе или вкладке?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не понятно как у вас "слетает фокус на вкладку которая закрыта".

Можно сохранять позицию перед "подгрузкой" и потом восстанавить:

```
//сохраняем позицию
Parcelable savedState=recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
//тут загрузка данных
...
//уведомляем адаптер об изменении данных
recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
//восстанавливаем позицию
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(savedState);
```